# Pandas: Delete rows based on multiple columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `A,B,C`. I have a list of tuples like `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ...]`. I would like to delete all rows that meet the following condition:
`(B=x1 && C=y1) | (B=x2 && C=y2) | ...` How can I do that in pandas? I wanted to use the `isin` function, but not sure if it is possible since my list has tuples. I could do something like this:

```
for x,y in tuples:   
    df = df.drop(df[df.B==x && df.C==y].index)
```

Maybe there is an easier way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use pandas indexing

```
df.set_index(list('BC')).drop(tuples, errors='ignore').reset_index()
```

---

#### Timing

```
def linear_indexing_based(df, tuples):
    idx = np.array(tuples)
    BC_arr = df[['B','C']].values
    shp = np.maximum(BC_arr.max(0)+1,idx.max(0)+1)
    BC_IDs = np.ravel_multi_index(BC_arr.T,shp)
    idx_IDs = np.ravel_multi_index(idx.T,shp)
    return df[~np.in1d(BC_IDs,idx_IDs)]

def divakar(df, tuples):
    idx = np.array(tuples)
    mask = (df.B.values == idx[:, None, 0]) & (df.C.values == idx[:, None, 1])
    return df[~mask.any(0)]

def pirsquared(df, tuples):
    return df.set_index(list('BC')).drop(tuples).reset_index()
```

**10 rows, 1 tuple**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(10), (10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
tuples = [tuple(row) for row in np.random.choice(range(10), (1, 2))]
```

[image]

**10,000 rows, 500 tuples**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(10), (10000, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
tuples = [tuple(row) for row in np.random.choice(range(10), (500, 2))]
```

[image]

Comment: Hahah that's slick!

Comment: Thanks! That `idx = np.array(tuples)` could be added to approach #2 I guess for fairness.

Comment: one sec. I missed that

Comment: This only works if tuples is an array/list **of** tuples right? Is that because the main dataframe becomes multi-indexed and needs tuples? For example, if the "tuples" is actually 2 columns in a second DataFrame, the only way I could think of was to extract them with something like `((x, y) for x, y in df2[['A', 'B']].values)` in the place of `tuples` which seems messy. Is there a better way to multi-index with the contents on a DataFrame?

Comment: That is messy and under certain circumstances incorrect.  You'd want `list(zip(df['A'], df['B']))`  OR the same thing but different `[*zip(*map(df.get, ['A', 'B']))]`

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def broadcasting_based(df, tuples):
    idx = np.array(tuples)
    mask = (df.B.values == idx[:, None, 0]) & (df.C.values == idx[:, None, 1])
    return df[~mask.any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [224]: df
Out[224]: 
   A  B  C
0  6  4  4
1  2  0  3
2  8  3  4
3  7  8  3
4  6  7  8
5  3  3  2
6  5  4  2
7  2  4  7
8  6  1  6
9  1  1  1

In [225]: tuples = [(3,4),(7,8),(1,6)]

In [226]: broadcasting_based(df,tuples)
Out[226]: 
   A  B  C
0  6  4  4
1  2  0  3
3  7  8  3
5  3  3  2
6  5  4  2
7  2  4  7
9  1  1  1
```

---

**Approach #2 : To cover a generic number of columns**

For a case like this, one could collapse the information from different columns into one single entry that would represent the uniqueness among all columns. This could be achieved by considering each row as indexing tuple. Thus, basically each row would become one entry. Similarly, each entry from the list of tuple that is to be matched could be reduced to a `1D` array with each tuple becoming one scalar each. Finally, we use `np.in1d` to look for the correspondence, get the valid mask and have the desired rows removed dataframe, Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def linear_indexing_based(df, tuples):
    idx = np.array(tuples)
    BC_arr = df[['B','C']].values
    shp = np.maximum(BC_arr.max(0)+1,idx.max(0)+1)
    BC_IDs = np.ravel_multi_index(BC_arr.T,shp)
    idx_IDs = np.ravel_multi_index(idx.T,shp)
    return df[~np.in1d(BC_IDs,idx_IDs)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be more efficient to [use boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) than a bunch of calls to `DataFrame.drop`. This is because Pandas doesn't have to reallocate memory in each loop iteration.

```
m = pd.Series(False, index=df.index)
for x,y in tuples:
    m |= (df.B == x) & (df.C == y)
df = df[~m]
```

Comment: @root haha you're absolutely right. Should've read more closely. Updating